# cl.exe unable to start when building Curlpp using msbuild

Tags: c++, visual-c++, msbuild, cl.exe

I am trying to build the libraries of curlpp on windows running visual studio 2015. I ran into many errors but most I fixed except this one. when I try to build the solution using the command

```
C:\curlpp-0.7.3>msbuild curlpp.VC9.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=DynamicLibDebugDynamicRTL
```

I end up with the error:

```
Project : error PRJ0002: Error result -1073741701 returned from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\cl.exe'.  

C:\curlpp-0.7.3\curlpp.VC9.sln] BSCMAKE : error BK1506: cannot open file '.\out\lib\DynamicLibDebugDynamicRTL\Easy.sbr': No such file or directory [C:\curlpp-0.7.3\curlpp.VC9.sln]
```

and a popup saying that CL.exe was unable to start 0xc0000007b

from the error it seems that it cant open a file. That dosent make any sense as the file is supposed to be built there. I think the CL.exe fails and thats the real problem. I think this problem is connected with me mixing or having wrong paths set.

the paths I am using are the following

```
X:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\amd64;
X:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK;
```

but ofc the problem could be somewhere else I got no clue at this point. when I manually run cl.exe from the vs9/amd64 folder it opens and works flawlessly. Thanks for any help

this is the readme I am following:

```
Open a command prompt and change folder to the root of curlpp tree.

set LIBCURL_PATH=/where/curl/is/installed
set OPENSSL_PATH=/where/openssl/is/installed (only if you have libcurl with ssl support and ssl installed)
msbuild curlpp.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=<Configuration>
    where <Configuration> is one of
    - DynamicLibDebugDynamicRTL
    - DynamicLibDebugStaticRTL
    - DynamicLibReleaseDynamicRTL
    - DynamicLibReleaseStaticRTL
    - StaticLibDebugDynamicRTL
    - StaticLibDebugStaticRTL
    - StaticLibReleaseDynamicRTL
    - StaticLibReleaseStaticRTL

Output files will be placed in a directory set in CURLPP_LIB_PATH.

Any of DynamicLib* configurations will build a .dll library file and a .lib library import file.
Any of StaticLib* configurations will build the .lib static (inline) library.
Any of *Debug* configurations will in addition build a .pdb Program Database file.
```

Comment: 0xc0000007b is STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT, the 99% case is a 32-bit process failing on loading a 64-bit dll.  Or the other way around.  Not a terrible mystery with your path settings, vc\bin contains the 32-bit compiler and VC\bin\amd64 contains the 64-bit compiler.  Drastically different version as well.  Don't mix.

Comment: I changed it but if I change it I get a "VCBuild.exe" missing as vcbuild.exe needs to be present and its in the amd64 folder. so In order to get vcbuild.exe I need to set the path to  amd64 and the build fails, I am pretty sure I am missing something as this seems crazy

Comment: You need to add more paths.  Don't do this yourself, use vc\vcvarsall.bat.